# StartActivity for result inside frgament handlr onactivityresult

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

I have `Activity-->FragmentA-->FragmentB1 & FRagmentB2`. When I call `startActivityForResult()` in `FragmentB`, how to handle the return data.
`Fragment A` has a `ViewPager` with `FragmentB1` and `FragmentB2`

In side a recyclerview .,,,i will be writing a onactivityresult inside the recycler adapter..how to handle it on onactivityresult inside FragmentB1

I have added the image of fragmentB1

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly Call like below from your fragment, you will get onActivityResult in that fragment itself

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(getActivity(), AnotherActivity.class), 1);
```

dont call with getActivity like below it will return the onActivityResult to the activity.

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(new Intent(getActivity(), AnotherActivity.class), 1);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44910187/recyclerview-with-in-recyclerview-with-start-activityonresult @Muthu

Comment: what do you want to tell..?

Comment: Activity origin = (Activity) context;
                origin.startActivityForResult(new Intent(getAppContext(), ContactsActivity.class), CONTACT_CODE); this code you are trying to say..?

Comment: how to acheive that output @muthu

Comment: Send the Fragment object to the adapter and perform startActivityForResult using the fragment.

Comment: your code helped me...thx...but the issue is once i add a contact...alll the recyclerview is getting updated...i want only the contact to be updated in the recyclerview item where we clicked plus icon and add contact to that particular item